# Layout with frames

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt4, pyqt5, qlayout

Currently working on a graphical user interface. I am trying to make the layout out of 3 QFrames.

As seen in the screenshot below, the **yellow** frame is on the right side. I would like that frame to be on top of the **right frame**. (On top of the numpad, taking the whole horizontal space)

Also, for the numpad buttons on the right frame. I would like them to be as close to each other as they can be, like a numpad on a keyboard. How would I adjust the grid to do that?

[image]

**EDITED**

This is how I want the outcome to be. Where the red frame is the rightTopFrame (Yellow frame in first picture).

[image]

**Code:**

```
def layoutUI(self):
        
        ### Right Top Frame
        self.rightTopFrame = QFrame()
        self.rightTopFrame.resize(1,1)
        self.rightTopFrame.setStyleSheet("background-color: yellow")
        
        
        ### Left Grid
        self.leftGrid = QGridLayout()
        self.leftGrid.setColumnMinimumWidth(10, 10)
        self.leftGrid.setRowMinimumHeight(1, 1) 
        
        # Run, Stop, Speed layout   
        self.leftGrid.addWidget(self.b1, 0, 0)
        self.leftGrid.addWidget(self.b2, 0, 2)
        
        self.leftGrid.addWidget(self.b3, 1, 0)
        self.leftGrid.addWidget(self.l1, 1, 1)
        self.leftGrid.addWidget(self.b4, 1, 2)  
        
        # pl (Pieces and Length) layout     
        self.leftGrid.addWidget(self.b5, 2, 0)
        self.leftGrid.addWidget(self.l2, 2, 1)
        self.leftGrid.addWidget(self.b6, 2, 2)
        
        self.leftGrid.addWidget(self.b7, 3, 0)
        self.leftGrid.addWidget(self.l3, 3, 1)
        self.leftGrid.addWidget(self.b8, 3, 2)
        
        # Manual
        self.leftGrid.addWidget(self.l4, 4, 1)
        
        self.leftGrid.addWidget(self.b9, 5, 0)
        self.leftGrid.addWidget(self.b10, 5, 1)
        self.leftGrid.addWidget(self.b11, 5, 2)



        
        ### Right Grid
        self.rightGrid = QGridLayout()
        self.rightGrid.setColumnMinimumWidth(0, 0)
        self.rightGrid.setRowMinimumHeight(1, 1)    
        
        
        
        self.rightGrid.addWidget(self.np1, 2, 0)
        self.rightGrid.addWidget(self.np2, 2, 1)
        self.rightGrid.addWidget(self.np3, 2, 2)
        self.rightGrid.addWidget(self.np4, 3, 0)
        self.rightGrid.addWidget(self.np5, 3, 1)
        self.rightGrid.addWidget(self.np6, 3, 2)
        self.rightGrid.addWidget(self.np7, 4, 0)
        self.rightGrid.addWidget(self.np8, 4, 1)
        self.rightGrid.addWidget(self.np9, 4, 2)
        self.rightGrid.addWidget(self.np0, 5, 1)
        self.rightGrid.addWidget(self.npCl, 5, 0)
        
        #self.rightGrid.addWidget(self.bExit, 0, 2)
        
        
        
                
        ### Left Frame
        self.leftFrame = QFrame()
        self.leftFrame.resize(150,550)
        #self.leftFrame.setStyleSheet("background-color: red")
        self.leftFrame.setLayout(self.leftGrid)
        
        ### Right Frame
        self.rightFrame = QFrame()
        self.rightFrame.resize(15,50)
        #self.rightFrame.setStyleSheet("background-color: green")
        self.rightFrame.setLayout(self.rightGrid)
        
        
        
        
        
        ### Main Grid
        self.mainGrid = QGridLayout()
        self.mainGrid.setColumnMinimumWidth(10, 0)
        self.mainGrid.addWidget(self.leftFrame)
        self.mainGrid.addWidget(self.rightFrame)
        self.mainGrid.addWidget(self.rightTopFrame)
        
        
        ### Main Interface
        self.setGeometry(300, 200, 850, 450)
        self.setLayout(self.mainGrid)
        self.setStyleSheet("background-color: %s" % backgroundColor)    
        self.setWindowTitle('Signal & slot')
        self.show()
```

Comment: You could put an image of what you want.

Comment: Added an image of how the result should be.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

In order for the frame to be underneath the numpad you must place them as a base. For the buttons to be together you must zero the space in the `QGridLayout` that contains them(`{your layout}.setSpacing(0)`), in addition to adding `QSpacerItem` around the QGridLayout. If you have any questions, I'll leave you the complete code.

```
import sys
from itertools import product

from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QFrame, QGridLayout, QHBoxLayout, QPushButton, QSizePolicy, QSpacerItem, QToolButton, QVBoxLayout, QWidget


class Widget(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Widget, self).__init__(parent=parent)
        self.layoutUI()

    def layoutUI(self):
        self.setStyleSheet("background-color: brown;")

        self.principalLayout = QHBoxLayout(self)

        self.rightFrame = QFrame(self)
        self.rightFrame.setFrameShape(QFrame.StyledPanel)
        self.rightFrame.setFrameShadow(QFrame.Raised)
        self.verticalLayout = QVBoxLayout(self.rightFrame)
        self.gridLayout = QGridLayout()

        btns = {(0, 0): "start", (0, 2): "Stop",
                (1, 0): "Speed-", (1, 1): "1", (1, 2): "Speed+",
                (2, 0): "Pieces", (2, 1): "0", (2, 2): "Clear",
                (3, 0): "Length", (3, 1): "0", (3, 2): "Clear",
                (4, 1): "Manual",
                (5, 0): "Cut", (5, 1): "Feed", (5, 2): "Clear"}
        for pos, name in btns.items():
            x, y = pos
            btn = QPushButton(self.rightFrame)
            btn.setText(name)
            self.gridLayout.addWidget(btn, x, y)

        self.verticalLayout.addLayout(self.gridLayout)
        self.principalLayout.addWidget(self.rightFrame)

        self.verticalLayoutR = QVBoxLayout()
        self.verticalLayoutR.setSpacing(0)
        self.exitFrame = QFrame(self)
        self.exitFrame.setStyleSheet("background-color: red;")
        self.exitFrame.setFrameShape(QFrame.StyledPanel)
        self.exitFrame.setFrameShadow(QFrame.Raised)
        self.exitverticalLayout = QVBoxLayout(self.exitFrame)
        self.exitBtn = QPushButton("Exit", self.exitFrame)
        self.exitverticalLayout.addWidget(self.exitBtn)
        self.verticalLayoutR.addWidget(self.exitFrame)

        self.numpadFrame = QFrame(self)
        self.numpadFrame.setStyleSheet("background-color: yellow;")
        self.numpadFrame.setFrameShape(QFrame.StyledPanel)
        self.numpadFrame.setFrameShadow(QFrame.Raised)
        self.horizontalLayout = QHBoxLayout(self.numpadFrame)
        spacerItem = QSpacerItem(2, 20, QSizePolicy.Expanding, QSizePolicy.Minimum)
        self.horizontalLayout.addItem(spacerItem)
        self.verticalLayout = QVBoxLayout()
        spacerItem1 = QSpacerItem(20, 57, QSizePolicy.Minimum, QSizePolicy.Expanding)
        self.verticalLayout.addItem(spacerItem1)
        self.gridLayout = QGridLayout()
        self.gridLayout.setSpacing(0)

        x = (0, 1, 2)

        coords = list(product(x, x))
        coords.append((3, 1))

        for coord in coords:
            x, y = coord
            button = QPushButton(self.numpadFrame)
            button.setFixedSize(60, 60)
            button.setText(str(x + 3 * y + 1))
            button.setStyleSheet("background-color: white;")
            self.gridLayout.addWidget(button, x, y)
        button.setText("0")

        self.verticalLayout.addLayout(self.gridLayout)
        spacerItem2 = QSpacerItem(20, 40, QSizePolicy.Minimum, QSizePolicy.Expanding)
        self.verticalLayout.addItem(spacerItem2)
        self.horizontalLayout.addLayout(self.verticalLayout)
        spacerItem3 = QSpacerItem(2, 20, QSizePolicy.Expanding, QSizePolicy.Minimum)
        self.horizontalLayout.addItem(spacerItem3)

        self.verticalLayoutR.addWidget(self.numpadFrame)

        self.adminFrame = QFrame(self)
        self.adminFrame.setStyleSheet("background-color: blue;")
        self.adminFrame.setFrameShape(QFrame.StyledPanel)
        self.adminFrame.setFrameShadow(QFrame.Raised)
        self.horizontalLayout = QHBoxLayout(self.adminFrame)
        spacerItem = QSpacerItem(40, 20, QSizePolicy.Expanding, QSizePolicy.Minimum)
        self.horizontalLayout.addItem(spacerItem)
        self.adminBtn = QPushButton("Admin", self.adminFrame)
        self.horizontalLayout.addWidget(self.adminBtn)
        self.verticalLayoutR.addWidget(self.adminFrame)
        self.principalLayout.addLayout(self.verticalLayoutR)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = Widget()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Output:

[image]