# How can I put the RadioBoxes over the Layout?

Tags: layout, pyqt, pyqt5, qradiobutton

I designed the following window. However, when running the code, the RadioBoxes stay behind the layout that contains the frame and the string. Could someone please tell me how to avoid this?

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
import sys

class Window(QWidget):
    
    def __init__(self): 
        super().__init__()
  
        self.setWindowTitle('Window')
        self.setFixedSize(550,440)
        self.LaySelf = QGridLayout()

        self.initWidgets()
        self.initUI()

        self.show()

    def initWidgets(self):

        self.Panel = QFrame()
        self.Panel.setFrameStyle(QFrame.StyledPanel)
        self.Panel.setLineWidth(2)
        self.Panel.setStyleSheet('background-color:#f4f2f1')

        self.Btt = QRadioButton('Radio',self)

        self.Label = QLabel(' '*40+'Hi')

    def initUI(self):

        self.LaySelf.addWidget(self.Panel,0,0,-1,6)
        self.LaySelf.addWidget(self.Label,0,0,-1,6)

        self.setLayout(self.LaySelf)

        self.Btt.move(200,200)

App = QApplication(sys.argv) 
window = Window()
sys.exit(App.exec())
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to make radio button on top of [QFrame](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qframe.html) you need to add it to the Frame. Currently the Radio Buttons stay behind Frame which is covering the layout. 
Replace `QRadioButton('Radio',self)` with `QRadioButton('Radio',self.Panel)`

Also here is a link to another thread which demostrates [Frame Usage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41483034/pyqt5-layout-with-frames) with multiple QWidgets