# Add layout inside QFrame()

Tags: python, pyqt5

I am beginner in the PyQt5

in my application I need to make (buttons, line edit, labels ...) in QVBoxLayout then puts everything on QFrame.

My Question:
Is It possible to make a layout (QHBoxLayout, QVBoxLayout, QFormeLayout ....) inside a QFrame ?

If possible, please tell me how to do .

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Layout with frames](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41483034/layout-with-frames)

Comment: Just use `setLayout()` on your frame. There's nothing to it.

Comment: All widgets inherit from QWidget (including QFrame), and since you can call `setLayout()` on any QWidget (or construct the layout with the widget as its parent argument to automatically set it), you can also theoretically do it for everything else that inherits from it. There are just some exceptions, like widgets that already have their own layout (QMainWindow, QStackedWidget) requiring to set a layout for their inner widgets, or widgets for which it makes no sense to have a layout due to their nature, like QComboBox or scroll areas (which eventually require a layout for their content).

Comment: In any case, before asking if it's possible, you should at least *try* to do it and show us your attempts in case they failed. If you need some guidance to use layouts in code, just look for tutorials, like [this one on zetcode](https://zetcode.com/gui/pyqt5/layout/). Also consider using Qt Designer for the UI (see how to [use layouts with it]https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/designer-layouts.html)), at least to understand the basics of layout managers, how they can be used, and to what widget types ("containers") they can be set.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Use a text editor or Qt Designer to create an .ui file. Here is a minimal example:

```
<widget class="QFrame" name="frame">
   <property name="geometry">
      <rect><x>60</x><y>40</y><width>160</width><height>100</height> 
</rect>
   </property>
   <layout class="QVBoxLayout" name="verticalLayout">
      <item><widget class="QPushButton" name="pushButton" /></item>
      <item><widget class="QLabel" name="label" /></item>
      <item><widget class="QLineEdit" name="lineEdit"/></item>
   </layout>
</widget>
```

It will look something like this:

[image]

**Python** example:

```
import sys
from PySide6.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget, QFrame, QLabel, QLineEdit, QPushButton, QVBoxLayout, QSpacerItem
app = QApplication(sys.argv)
window = QWidget()
window.setGeometry(300,300,300,100)
frame = QFrame(window)
layout = QVBoxLayout(frame)
pushButton = QPushButton("pushButton")
layout.addWidget(pushButton)
label = QLabel("label")
layout.addWidget(label)
lineEdit = QLineEdit("lineEdit")
layout.addWidget(lineEdit)
window.show()
app.exec()
```

**C++** example:

```
void QtWidgetsApplication1::setupUi(QMainWindow* window) {
  
   frame = new QFrame(window);
   window->setCentralWidget(frame);

   verticalLayout = new QVBoxLayout(frame);

   pushButton = new QPushButton(frame);
   pushButton->setText("pushButton");
   verticalLayout->addWidget(pushButton);

   label = new QLabel(frame);
   label->setText("label");
   verticalLayout->addWidget(label);

   lineEdit = new QLineEdit(frame);
   lineEdit->setText("lineEdit");
   verticalLayout->addWidget(lineEdit);

   verticalSpacer = new QSpacerItem(20, 40, QSizePolicy::Minimum, QSizePolicy::Expanding);
   verticalLayout->addItem(verticalSpacer);
}
```

Comment: No need to .ui files here. This is perfectly doable with just code.

Comment: Indeed, there is no need for .ui files. Some people might find it easier to use though. Plus, you can use it in applications written either in C++ or Python. Think about it.